how to make curved from the top Flutter bottom navigation bar
I want to make this curved bottom nav bar in Flutter 


but what I'm getting is this


I'm using ClipRRect to do it but it's not what I need, and here is my code
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(500),topLeft: Radius.circular(500),),
          color: Color(0xfff2f2f2),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey,
              offset: Offset(5.0, 10.0), //(x,y)
              blurRadius: 20.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(500),topLeft: Radius.circular(500),),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset(logo,height: HDW().fullHeight(context: context,height: 0.1),color: darkGreen,),label: ''),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset(logo,height: HDW().fullHeight(context: context,height: 0.1),color: darkGreen,),label: ''),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),



You can use the CustomPaint widget, with it you can build any shape that you want in Flutter
This video can help you to design and implement a custom shape for the bottom navigation bar.
Link: Flutter - Custom Shaped Bottom Navigation Bar

well, after understanding the video link and changing the codes, that's worked, thank tou a lot dear

well, still have problem with the elevation, tried to use Material...BoxShadow, the didn't worked, do you have any idea?

Ok, now you can try using your shape in the Stack widget or put your shape as a child of the SizedBox or Container widget and set the height for that, it should be much more than your shape for display elevation.

@HusamuldeenAbdlrahman

finally I used an image in a stack  with Row of IconButton to solve the issue
